# python не видит swig

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я поставил swig для того, чтобы работала библиотека Box2D.
В cmd swig работает, а вот python в pycharm его не видит
[image: Код ошибки,]

Если что я использую официальных код из github

> https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/bipedal_walker.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым, вместо библиотеки Box2D, я поставил box2d-py и все заработало)